# Shake event detection in all view controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, oop, events

Is this possible in iOS, or do I really have to register a shake event detection in every single view controller?

I want that a user of my app can shake his iPhone to return to the root. Regardless of the current view controller.

Comment: Just some advice, this could be annoying if the user tosses their phone onto their bed or turns it sideways and it registers as a shake. I haven't checked the HIG regarding this specific case, but it could be in violation. As a user, I would find this annoying. I hope you add a setting to turn that off if you do decide to continue on this path.

Comment: Good point! I guess I'll add a setting to deactivate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this by writing a category on UIViewController. This way you don't need to subclass anything, you can implement it even if the user interface has been finished already.

In my implementation, the VCs will respond to the shake **unless** the specific VC has opted out of the mechanism. Opting out is done by setting a BOOL ivar to NO in the specific implementation. The shake mechanism will look for this ivar using key-value-coding and ignore the shake if the ivar has been set.

I'd further refine this by allowing only the VC to respond which is currently visible.

Answer (score 0):

**edited post (old information was wrong)**

in your case I would write my own ViewController which subclasses `UIViewController`, implements the motion-delegates of `UIResponder` and will then call the `popToRootViewController` on the `navigationController`-property of the ViewController. And everytimes you create a new ViewController you should subclass *your* ViewCOntroller and not `UIViewController`. So every ViewController is able to receive the shake-event but it is only written once in your code :)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but maybe you could do it by subclassing UIApplication (not your app delegate, the actual application). UIApplication is a UIResponder, so you can make it the first responder, and provide a motionBegan or motionEnded method on it.